# jQuery remote validate not showing an error message DJango

Tags: python, django, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery remote validation to check whether an email is available to register by calling DJango view.

views.py

```
def check_email(request):
  is_available = "false"
  if request.is_ajax():
    username = request.POST.get("username")
    try: 
        User.objects.get_by_natural_key(username)
    except User.DoesNotExit:
       is_available = "true"
  return HttpResponse(is_available)
```

url.py

```
    url(r'^check_email/$', 'app.views.check_email', name='check_email')
```

jQuery

```
{$( "#myform" ).validate({
rules: {
    email: { remote: "check-email/" }
}
messages: {
   email: {remote: "The email is already taken."}
}
});
```

The jQuery code is not rendering the error message. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: your url config (check_emails/) and your url in email rule(check-emails/), doesn't match

Comment: You might wanna try returning `True` and `False` instead of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def check_email(request):
    is_available = "false"
    if request.is_ajax():
        username = request.GET.get("username") # Change post to get
        try: 
            User.objects.get_by_natural_key(username)
        except User.DoesNotExit:
            is_available = "true"
    return HttpResponse(is_available)
```

and

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        email: { 
            remote: "/check-email/",
            type: "get", // get method
        }
    }, // add comma
    messages: {
       email: {remote: "The email is already taken."}
    }
});
```